# Compiling error whilst using command from NASM and mingw

Tags: windows, assembly, mingw, x86-64, nasm

I want to play a bit with assembly. To get started I've created [a little asm script](https://pastebin.com/gNLQTFhh) and tried to compile it. In the first step everything went great:

> ```
> nasm -felf64 hello.asm
> ```

But when I tried to use

> ```
> ld -o hello.o hello
> ```

from MinGW an error occured:

> ```
> hello.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
> ```

What can I do to fix this problem? I've tried it with gcc as well but then the same error plus one other error occurs.

Comment: isn't that with `-o` you specify the output file? so shouldn't it be `ld -o hello hello.o`? But then the error is kinda strange

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

MinGW creates binaries targeting Windows. Windows does not support ELF binaries (or does it? with Windows subsystem for Linux?). Anyway, `ld` in MinGW will expect that you provide binaries in `win64` format not `elf64`.

`nasm -fwin64 hello.asm` will most likely work.

---

No it won't work because I just saw your code, and you are using Linux syscalls under Windows.

Write,

```
mov rcx, 69
call ExitProcess
```

instead of,

```
mov rax, SYS_EXIT
mov rdi, 69
syscall
```

Leave a comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux is sort of like a virtual machine. (Or in WSL2 literally is a virtual machine).  I don't know whether it lets Linux GUI programs make separate Windows windows or if there's a window containing the GNU/Linux desktop.  But anyway, that doesn't really count; they're not *native* Windows binaries, and MinGW won't make them.